# Highlight current menu item in sidebar

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using django with Twitter Bootstrap.  My current view resembles one of the [examples provided](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html).  Looking at the example, one can imagine the user clicking one of the links in the sidebar to see different views, each framed with this same sidebar.  One would imagine that the link selected would then be highlighted just like the example using the code:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/sample/link/here/">Link</a></li>
```

The active class needs to be attached to the correct menu item.  How might I assign this "active" class to the correct menu item?  Originally, I tried using a variable from my view to assign it with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#{{ current_view }}_nav").addClass('active');
});

<li id="linkone_nav"><a href="/sample/link/here/">Link</a></li>
```

This seems cumbersome though.  It requires that I pass the id to the template from the view.  Lots of ids to manage as well.  Is there a better / more preferred way to assign this active class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your use of `#` for the href in your sample code is clouding the issue. I'm assuming your real-world scenario is actual real links and automatically highlighting them based on the active URL. If that's correct, then just do:

```
{% url something as url %}
<li{% if request.path == url %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url }}">Link1</a></li>
```

Where, "something" is the name of a urlpattern or dotted-path to a view, etc. This assumes you're reversing the URL, obviously, so if you're using a static URL, you'd just hardcode it:

```
<li{% if request.path == "/my/full/url/path/" %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/my/full/url/path/">Link1</a></li>
```

Comment: ah, this is more in the way of what I'm looking for.  Sorry for the ambiguity.  Had just copied from the bootstrap source for reference.  I'll give this a shot!

Answer (score 7):

If you've organized your project into a `base.html` template that is extended by other templates, e.g. `appname/pagename.html`, you can use a template-centric approach to highlighting the active navigation element.

This approach gives you some decoupling advantages, which I've noted in detail at the end of this answer.

I've found this approach to be very useful for handling broad navigation items that remain the same across most or all of a site.  It is probably not an appropriate solution for more detailed navigation elements, such as rendering a dynamic list of items gleaned from your data store.

In your `base.html` template, add a block to each navigation element, giving unique names to the blocks:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="{% block navbar_class-home %}{% endblock %}">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="{% block navbar_class-about %}{% endblock %}">
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="{% block navbar_class-pricing %}{% endblock %}">
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your `appname/pagename.html` template, if you want one of the nav elements to appear active, override the appropriate block using `active` as the content.  For example, to highlight the "About" item:

```
{% block navbar_class-about %} active {% endblock %}
```

When you use a view that renders that template, it'll render like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class=" active ">
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This provides an initial rendering that doesn't rely on JavaScript.  (You can modify the nav bar classes in place using JavaScript if you're doing a single-page app.)

For many (but not all) cases, this can be a better separation presentation from view logic:

- You can modify views to attach site-navigation data to the template context, but doing so strongly couples the presentation to the view layer, and makes it more difficult to create reusable apps or to integrate third-party apps.

  The view is already selecting a named template, which means that you are already passing some navigation-related information to the template layer.  That may be all you need.
- You can use a template context processor to get some information about the view, but this just moves the strong coupling to another layer of the system, rather than staying within the template layer.

Answer (score 2):

Better solution, with less code. Woks well with Bootstrap. Just change the "addClass" query to select your menu items.

On Javascript, create this function:

```
var highlight_menu = function(path) {
    /* Highlight current link */    
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + path + '"])').addClass('active')
};
```

On the base.html, call the JS function with the current path:

```
<script>
    highlight_menu('{{request.path}}');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the Twitter Bootstrap page itself has this functionality provided by using the [Scrollspy plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy).

Otherwise, you could just listen to a click event in your menu.

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li:has(a[href^="#"])', function (e) {
  $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't quite applicable though.  My links aren't anchors on the same page.  They are referencing other pages that share the same menu (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

Make an inclusion snippet for your menu:

```
<li class="{% if opt=='link1' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#/?opt=link1">Link1</a></li>
<li class="{% if opt=='link2' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#/?opt=link2">Link2</a></li>
<li class="{% if opt=='link3' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#/?opt=link3">Link3</a></li>
...
```

Include it in your basic template as:

```
{% include "menu.html" with opt=request.GET.opt %}
```

You don't need to use $( document ).ready(...) as you see.

Don't forget to add a request to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  # ...
  'django.core.context_processors.request',
  # ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following approach to resolve the issue in Django.

It works fine without using javascript. Just by using the pure Django you should be able to address the most of the situations where you need to highlight menu  options.

In this example I am using Bootstrap 4 but it is not important. You can use your own CSS and you will be ok. The idea here is just to show the use of **request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name** to achieve what you need.

```
{% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="{% if url_name == 'your url' %}nav-item active{% else %}nav-item{% endif %}">
       <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'your url 1' %}">Menu option 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="{% if url_name == 'your url' %}nav-item active{% else %}nav-item{% endif %}">
       <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'your url 2' %}">Menu option 2</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a a simple_tag for that purpose. Maybe someone will find it helpful.

Make a file isactive.py and put in your templatetags directory on the level of your app template path.

```
from django import template
from django import urls
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def isactive(page_name, request_url):
    rev_url = ''
    try:     
        rev_url = urls.reverse(page_name)
    except:
        return ''
    if (rev_url == request_url):
            return 'active'
    return ''
```

And in your html template

```
{% load isactive %}
```

after loading static
and in your menu

```
<a href="{% url 'my_table_list' %}" class="nav-link {% isactive 'my_table_list' request.path %}">
```

When rendering - django is executing function isactive where 1st parameter is the name of the page and the other is the path. Inside the isactive function the name is resolved and compared. When it matches the active string is returned and placed in resulting html.
You have to put that call in every nav link.

The name of the page is taken from urlpatterns in urls.py of your app

```
urlpatterns = (
    ...
    path("my_table/list/", views.mytableListView.as_view(), name="my_table_list"),
    ....
```

Comment: What happens if there are any GET parameters in the URL ? Maybe you should replace your condition to check if `request_url` starts with the same as `rev_url`

Comment: Good question! But the django docs say : "
HttpRequest.path

    A string representing the full path to the requested page, not including the scheme, domain, or query string.

    Example: "/music/bands/the_beatles/"

Comment: ...Still.. If there are objects' ids passed it will need to compare starting strings only. But then we can end with duplicates....